# Why is one class-inside-a-class not in the scope of another class-inside-a-class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scoping

Consider the following code:

```
from enum import Enum

class A(object):
    class B(object):
        blah = "foo"
        derp = "bar"

    class SubA(object):
        def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            self.value = B.derp
```

This raises a NameError

```
>>> A.SubA()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.value = B.derp
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

On the other hand, replacing `B.derp` with `A.B.derp` makes the code work as desired.

Why does Python's scoping resolve this in the way it does, and why *should* this make sense in Python's design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/), the class body's scope is not available from inside other scopes nested inside it.  So the reason you get a NameError for `B` in your example is the same reason you get a NameError in this case:

```
class Foo(object):
    x = 88
    def foo(self):
        print(x)
```

Functions defined in the class body (i.e., methods) don't have access to the class body scope; neither do nested classes (or functions nested inside those).

`A.B.derp` works because `A` is in *global* scope, which is always accessible.

However, note that even `A.B.derp` won't work if you try to use it directly in the class body:

```
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        derp = 88
    class SubA(object):
        stuff = A.B.derp
```

This won't work because the line referring to `A.B.derp` is executed during the process of creating `A`, so `A` doesn't exist yet and can't be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Although classes define a new namespace, they don't create a scope for names used inside of bodies of methods. While referring to them the names have to be fully qualified. That what `self.something` or `cls.something` are for.

Try using a fully qualified name like `A.B.something`. `A` is in the same namespace as `B` but not in the same variable scope.